# Syncfusion React Grid - React 15 compatibility

Tags: reactjs, grid, compatibility, syncfusion

I'm using the syncfusion react grid on an environment where I cannot upgrade from React 15.6.2, which means no portal, no hooks etc etc etc.

Syncfusion should be compatible, but it is with few glitches. Especially since portals arent there every template functionality isn't working, as well as aggregates and few others.

I tried to find in the release tree if there was an old version of the grid that would support completely react 15, but I couldn't.

Does anyone know if there is a way top have fully functional grids in react 15.6.2 ? Or would you suggest another grid component that achieves the same ? What we need, as main features, are batch editing, copy/paste horizontal and vertical, aggregates (row and columns), grouping, filtering, cell templating and that's about it

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your query and found that you have used the react 15.6.2 in your Grid application. Since the react essential features are introduced from react 16.0.0 versions, we have updated our Grid component rendering flow based on latest react version. So, to use all the Grid related feature we suggest you update your react to latest version.